# wildcard search with multiple parameters in MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table named 'contacts'. which consists of some columns. One of the column's name is 'name'. 
I want to create a wildcard search using multiple search parameter in name column in one query. 
How do I find multiple records using LIKE phrase?

I have tried this code.

```
SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE NAME LIKE '%Sudipta%', '%Hasanuzzaman%', '%Jawad%';
```

I expected This result:

```
id    |  name             |
----------------------------
254   | Sudipta Kumar     | 
280   | Sudipta Chowdhury | 
402   | Hasanuzzaman Khan | 
452   | MD. Hasanuzzaman  | 
469   | Jawad Karim       |
```

But this error message has been displayed:

Error Code: 1064 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' '%Hasanuzzaman%', '%Jawad%' LIMIT 0, 1000' at line 1

Please tell me the query to do the above action...

Comment: Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: ok, thanx for ur suggestion. @Strawberry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use LIKE OR Operator in query

```
SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE NAME LIKE '%Sudipta%' OR NAME LIKE '%Hasanuzzaman%' OR NAME LIKE '%Jawad%';
```

Hope this help you

Comment: Welcome @Prodiptukhor